# Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]"

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I try to remove "competences" by ID

DDB modele :
competences

```
id(from firebase): - competence: "string"
                   - definition: "string"
                   - icon: "string"
```

i use :

```
  deleteData(key){
    firebase.database().ref('competences/').child(key).remove();
}

 <tbody>
   {this.state.items.map((element) => {
        return (<tr>
                   <td>{element.competence}</td>
                   <td>{element.definition}</td>
                   <td><img src={element.icon} style={imgStyle}/></td>
                   <td><button onclick={this.deleteData(element)}>supp</button></td>
                 </tr>)
   })}
 </tbody>
```

But i've a error :
Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

[console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2wuC.png)

Comment: what is key equal to?

Comment: normaly for competences UID, no? is a child of ref('competences/')

Comment: is `competences` the database name? try this `firebase.database().ref().child(key).remove();`

Comment: I suppose you need to use

`<button onclick={() => this.deleteData(element.competence)}>supp</button></td>`

Comment: @PeterHaddad : TypeError: pathString.replace is not a function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes i try on first time but he add new competences on my BDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the the key which is a string `(element.competence)`, but what you are passing is an object `element`